# How to show navigation icon to open the navigation drawer by recycler view

Tags: android

I am not able to show navigation icon in my app .How is it possible to show it to open navigation drawer by recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
declare

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle abdt;
private DrawerLayout dl;
```

then in your onCreate() function, after you set your dl() add this:

```
abdt = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.yourIcon, R.string.drawOpen, R.string.drawClose);
dl.setDrawerListener(abdt);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```